# Flutter - Cells spannable table view

Tags: flutter

I just looking for a widget type where it provides a simple default solution to draw shared border lines between children widgets, instead of touching two different borders or turning a widget into a border. Basically it's just a table thing with the children as it's cell widgets.

There's `Table` in Flutter. But sadly seems like the cells is unspannable. No "colspan" thing for it's `TableCell`. If I put `TableRow`s with different numbers of `TableCells`, I get error

> Table contains irregular row lengths. Every TableRow in a Table must
> have the same number of children, so that every cell is filled.
> Otherwise, the table will contain holes.

I used to do it with Java.

```
<TableLayout ...>
     <TableRow ...>
          <... android:layout_span .../>
     </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

I just want to do it again with Flutter. That's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by simply put inner table inside outer table's cell.

```
Table(
  children : [
    TableRow( //This row will contains virtually spanned cell
      children: [
        TableCell(...),
      ],
    ),
    TableRow( //This row will contains indirectly unspanned cells
      children: [
        TableCell(
          child : Table(...),
        ),
      ],
    )
  ]
);
```

And then remove outer borders for inner table leaving only inner borders.

```
TableBorder(
    horizontalInside : BorderSide(
      color : Colors.grey,
    ),
    verticalInside : BorderSide(
      color : Colors.grey,
    ),
)
```

I don't know whether it's a workaround or just how Flutter deal with it because I got the answer from Flutter's github

Answer (score 0):

[`ListView.separated`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.separated.html) might be what you are looking for

It takes the following arguments

- `itemBuilder` for the content of your rows
- `separatorBuilder` for creating a dynamic separator between your cells. You could use the `Divider` widget for that purpose.

Comment: sorry not working. table is better yet gave me nothing

Comment: What exactly "is not working"? Do you want to create another question for it?

Comment: no. i think you need to read my question properly